# Add google fonts to html

Tags: html, fonts

I have html page and I want to add 2 google font to my page. And I try to add 2 fonts in one row:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400|Roboto:400">
```

But I get validation error ( validator.w3.org )

```
Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.
```

So is it possible to add 2 google fonts in one row?

Answer (score 0):

Try to linking what google fonts generate for you after making the selection, since what you have up there looks a bit different.